# Ajax не работает в PhoneGap

Tags: phonegap, ajax, android

Здравствуйте. Пишу HTML5 App под `Android`. Столкнулся с тем, что PhoneGap не подгружает через `Ajax` данные при загрузке страницы. Хотя функция с `$.ajax` вызывается и сразу после загрузки, и по клику на кнопке, по клику она запускается, но не подгружает при загрузке документа. Как исправить?

Comment: Р[азрешите нужный url](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.5.0/guide_whitelist_index.md.html#Domain%20Whitelist%20Guide)

Comment: Данные беру из API ВКонтакте. Вот что дописал:

<access origin="https://api.vk.com" />
<access origin="http://vk.com" subdomains="true" />
<access origin="https://vk.com" subdomains="true" />
<access origin="*" />

Ничего не изменилось...

Comment: Ошибки не вываливаются?

Answer (score 1):

js:

```
        $.ajax({
            url:url,
            cache:false,
            type: 'POST',
            data: {'id':1,'do':'delete'},
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            jsonp: 'jsoncallback',
            timeout: 5000,
            error: function(xhr,status,error) {
                  alert('some problems');
            },
          success: function(ret) {
               alert(ret.success);
           }
```

php:

```
    <?php echo $_REQUEST['jsoncallback'] . '(' . json_encode(array('success' => "want to {$_REQUEST['do']} item with id:{$_REQUEST['id']}")) . ')'; ?>
```